# Why does Mail.app automatically add iCal events from invitations I receive?

Tags: mail.app, ical

I sometimes receive emails with .ics file attachments. Mail.app automatically adds these events to my iCloud Calendar as soon as I preview the message.

How can I disable this behaviour and only add the event if I click on the attachment manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [web app preferences to manage this in newer macOS.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259750/5472)

In the Mail.app go to Preferences->general. There is an option "Add invitations to ICal" which is Automatic or None. You need to choose None.

[image: Mail preferences]

When you have a mail with date and time in Mail.App will highlight that and clicking on that will add an event to iCal.

Comment: Doh! I swear I looked in the preferences - but it was hiding right there in the middle :) Thanks!