# Spam iCloud Calendar Invitations

Tags: icloud, email, calendar, ical, spam

Today I've suddenly received spam calendar invitation for $19.99 Ray Ban sunglasses (never subscribed, checked, searched or visited any related site, so clearly spam) and it has other visible email accounts within the invitation.

I'm wondering if I should be worried whether my accounts been compromised or a simple email from anywhere just plops this in my calendar without review.

Questions to be answered:

1. What should I check/setup in order to make sure my iCloud account is safe?
2. How can I delete this invitation without sending a notification to the sender, so as to prevent them from knowing my email address is live?
3. How can I prevent these notifications in the future?

Here's an image:

[image]

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Regarding how to prevent this in the future (question #3):

1. Log in to [iCloud Calendar](https://www.icloud.com/#calendar) on a computer web browser
2. Authenticate if needed, then select the Calendar view
3. Select the Settings Gear icon ⚙ in the bottom left corner then hit **`Preferences...`**

[image: preferences]

4. Select **Advanced**

Choose the option to receive calendar invitations by email instead of allowing the server to insert them without review into your calendar:

[image: Email invitations setting]

5. Select **`Email to [youremail]`** instead of `In-app notifications`

You now get to decide and delete or process calendar spam like regular email spam, allowing you to filter out these spam calendar invitations systematically.

Comment: This is the best answer for preventing future spam.  Thank you.

Comment: @RLH - Make sure you're in the calendar preferences, not the general iCloud settings - I made that mistake.

Comment: The iCloud.com Calendar interface now lets you [report invitations as spam](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/12/12/apple-activates-icloudcom-calendar-spam-reporting-feature).

Answer (score 68):

I've had the exact same email. I've managed to get rid of it by doing the following:

1. Create a new iCloud calendar - I called mine junk
2. Move the spam invite to the new Junk calendar
3. Delete the newly created Junk calendar with the spam appointment in it - ensuring you select the 'Delete and Don't Notify' option in the Dialog box that appears.

This worked for me - I hope it works for you too.

Comment: This is *not* good advice. I checked this using an iCloud invite from another account - the dialogue that comes up when you delete the junk calendar offers the option to delete the calendar and not notify. However, my status is updated to declined in the calendar of the person who sent the invite. It is possible that spammers can still detect your email address is real if you use this.

Answer (score 11):

Apple made a 'report junk' button inside the calendar app on iCloud.com - when you report an invite it will be deleted across all synced calendars.

> If you get an invitation that you think is junk or spam, you can
>   report it to iCloud.
>
> 1. Sign in to iCloud.com with your Apple ID, then click Calendar.
> 2. Open the event you want to report, then click Report Junk.
> 3. Click OK.
>
> The event is automatically deleted from your calendar on all your
>   devices where you’re signed in with the same Apple ID.

[image: Screenshot iCloud.com Calendar]

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't currently seem possible using the accepted answer, at least if the inviter is in your contacts - it needs some sort of action from Apple. Please make a comment if there is extra privacy against invites from people not in your contacts (I thought it worth making an answer for this, given that information still seems to leak).

I tried the accepted answer: sent an invite to my iCloud account from a different iCloud event and followed the accepted answer. The sending account saw the event as declined. It's not clear whether spammers can see this using their method but it's ***definitely*** possible that they can.

I also tried moving the invite into a Junk calendar without deleting it and even this action can be seen - the inviter sees something like "Deleted from Home".

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: It's somewhere in-between. Based on what I've seen, the accepted answer is wrong and the current answer to most of the question is "no, it's not possible to prevent this". Answers can change over time if new information comes to light.

Comment: I agree the accepted answer is less than ideal. I've put a [bounty on the answer currently with the most votes](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259750/5472) to indicate it's a nice way to prevent this class of nuisance as opposed to dealing with each instance.

Comment: @bmike 1. I've changed accepted answer (didn't know this was possible) so your comment / bounty may need to be updated, if so is required. 2. By the time previous answer was accepted, it was the only one that solved the problem. 3. Is there a need to change question / answers so they could be more helpful to the community?

Comment: @DenisRasulev - you can always change the accepted. Bounty will help others see the fix so o harm there (that I see). I don't see any need for edits. Good questions though.

Answer (score 3):

With regard to #2 (how to delete without sending a notification to the sender) -- I don't have an answer yet, but I can confirm that the up-voted answer from Jackal above ("move spam event into temporary calendar, then delete temporary calendar") **still sends a DECLINE to the sender.**

Understandably many folks here and in other social media venues that are sharing the workaround have **merely trusted** the "Delete and Don't Notify" button on the calendar-with-open-invites-delete warning to do what it says it does.

This, however, is Stack, where we should promote testability, repeatability and empirical evidence in general.

This is simply tested and currently repeatable on latest build of macOS and Calendar at this time of writing: simply have another iCloud user send you an invite, and have them watch your acceptance-status change from NO REPLY to DECLINED, the moment you click "Delete and Don't Notify" on for that temporary calendar.

So far, @AppleSupport has yet to respond with anything except "PM us with your device and OS versions."

In the meantime, I have 5 spam invites filling my calendar that I'm not touching.

And no, I am not interested in turning OFF the direct-from-email-to-calendar feature, as it is a good feature, it just needs "show invites in calendar automatically, but only for senders in my contacts" and a "swipe-left-to-delete-the-invite" ... and then actually NOT send a decline.